# How to count rightmouse clicks on java?

Tags: java, mouse

```
public class ClickButtonClass implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent cbc)
    {
        clickcounter++;
        clicklabel.setText("Clicks: "+clickcounter);
    }
}
```

I did this code for counting clicks. But it only counts left mouse clicks. How do I add right mouse clicks too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `MouseListener`.  Here is an example:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("click me");
        label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
            if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(me)) {
                System.out.println("right click");
            } else {
                System.out.println("left click");
            }
        });

        frame.getContentPane().add(label);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an ActionListener.

Instead you should be using a `MouseListener`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for more information and examples.

Answer (score 0):

To count rightclicks:

```
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
public class Demo extends Frame { 
    Integer counter=0;
    Button btn; 
     Label label;
    public Demo() { 
        setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
        btn = new Button("OK");   
        label= new Label("Number of rightclicks: "+counter);
btn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getModifiers() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3_MASK) { 
            counter++;
            label.setText("Number of rightclicks: " +counter.toString());} } 
        });   

        add(btn); 
        add(label);
        setSize(300,300); 
        setVisible(true);

        }   
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        new Demo(); 
        } 
    }
```